# Kong 2.0.2 Serving api and static content

Tags: nginx, kong

**Problem**: I am trying to customize the nginx config that gets generated by kong to serve static content as well as my api [as described here](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/configuration/#serving-both-a-website-and-your-apis-from-kong). I can get the `nginx.conf` file to be generated, but for the life of me -I can't get my simple HTML to be served.

**What I've Done**: I've created a minimal `docker-compose` that reproduces my issue [here](https://github.com/tysmithnet/test-nginx). I've tried all sorts of combinations here and I universally get the same result:

`{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}`

The only logs I can see that are relevant are:

```
2020/04/04 06:20:11 [warn] 49#0: *11361 using uninitialized "kong_proxy_mode" variable, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/04/04 06:20:11 [warn] 49#0: *11361 using uninitialized "ctx_ref" variable, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/04/04 06:20:11 [warn] 49#0: *11361 [lua] reports.lua:75: log(): [reports] unknown request scheme: http while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
```

I've tried moving `root` out of `location`, using `alias` instead of `root`, passing a host header, changing the `server_name`, and a thousand other things I can't remember.

I *believe* the problem lies [here](https://github.com/tysmithnet/test-nginx/blob/master/custom_nginx.template#L122) but I have no idea at this point. I think this is the problem because I can get it to return text if I change the body to:

```
location / { 
  return 200 'huh?';
}
```

Any help would add a few years back to my life.

**EDIT**
I [stripped out everything](https://github.com/tysmithnet/test-nginx/tree/barebones) except the bare essentials for `location /` and `location /api/` and this works -so I can try building up from here to find the cause.

**EDIT**
It appears as though [this commit](https://github.com/tysmithnet/test-nginx/commit/59e0a58c29a38f4738a8220187ffba7e4180d90e) contains the breaking change, it's unclear to me what the breaking change is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to isolate the problem, and in hindsight it was quite obvious. These kong directives need to go only inside the location block for api, and not for the static content.

```
            rewrite_by_lua_block {
                Kong.rewrite()
            }
            access_by_lua_block {
                Kong.access()
            }
            header_filter_by_lua_block {
                Kong.header_filter()
            }
            body_filter_by_lua_block {
                Kong.body_filter()
            }
            log_by_lua_block {
                Kong.log()
            }
```

See the commit that fixed the issue [here](https://github.com/tysmithnet/test-nginx/commit/9b38d24ec32bae53832daad5d670a7d4322bed6d)